# Select JSON elements from nested document

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-11

I have a JSON document such as:

```
{ "type" : "episode", "AssetId" : "urn:episode:ABCDEFG", "_id" : { "$oid" : "12345678" } }
```

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "v22"."assets_exp" (
    "_id" UUID NOT NULL,
.......
 "references.descendants" JSON,
.......
```

I would like to select `type`,  `AssetId` in addition to `"$oid"` as `"_id"`.

I tried `json_populate_record`:

```
CREATE TYPE descendant_t AS (
    "type" text,
    "AssetId" text
);

select r.* 
from  "v22"."assets_exp", 
lateral json_populate_record(null::descendant_t, "references.descendants") r;
```

...but I get an error message, either that

> function json_populate_record doesn't exist

or

> ERROR: cannot call populate_composite on an array.

Any ideas?

The only function that works on this data is `json_array_elements_text`.

I am using PostgreSQL 11 and the data is imported from Mongo hence the naming of the columns.

Comment: Your version of Postgres is obviously relevant.

Comment: `function json_populate_record doesn't exist` is not a Postgres error message, which would look like `ERROR:  function json_populate_record(myrowtype2, text) does not exist`. Please *always* show verbatim error messages. And is there an actual column named `assets_exp."references.descendants"`? (Really?!) Arriving at my mantra: please disclose your actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` script).